# Not able to set editview id while sending this from another activity

Tags: android

Thank you every one for giving time to this question.
   I have one editview that I need to append when I call appendToMessageHistory method from another Activity.
    second Activity

```
    EditText et;
    Messaging msg = new Messaging(getApplicationContext(), et);
    msg.appendToMessageHistory(username, messegestr);
```

on Messaging Activity.

```
private EditText messageHistoryText;
messageHistoryText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageHistory);

private Context mCon;

    public Messaging(Context applicationContext, EditText name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.mCon = applicationContext;
        this.messageHistoryText = name;
    }

public Messaging() {

    }//by default constructor  

public void appendToMessageHistorysend(String username, String message) {
        if (username != null && message != null) {

            if (messageHistoryText != null) {
                                messageHistoryText.append(Html
                                        .fromHtml(username1));
                                messageHistoryText.append(Html
                                        .fromHtml(message1));
                            }

                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(mCon,
                                        "hey yo not working value are null",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

I still get null for messageHistoryText.
and app crash 
again thank you for your time

Comment: Why you need to pass entire edit text? pass only text entered by user. pass et.getText. And use that text in Messaging.

Comment: Is `Messaging` an `Activiy` ?

Comment: yes messaging is a activity

Comment: @EagleEye first i only send value but still i got messageHistoryText  instance null only..

Answer (score 0):

In your first block of code:

```
EditText et;
Messaging msg = new Messaging(getApplicationContext(), et);
msg.appendToMessageHistory(username, messegestr);
```

the object "et" is not initialized... it will crash if you try to access it.

Comment: EditText et=null 
and EditText et=(Edittext)findviewbyId(R.id.sometex);
But first case objective doesnt complete and in second case i was tring to access id from another layout.

Comment: post your actual code then, not pieces of it. I answered assuming it was executing in a specific order, but then realize you don't really specify any order at all... if you are calling the "first set of code" from "another activity" it is not clear what order things are happening, what is set / not set, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Activity life-cycle is managed by the Android framework. Writing a custom constructor in an Activity is a big mistake (overriding an existing constructor is some rare cases useful).

When you develop for Android you should never call an Activity constructor in your own code. And when I say *never* I mean **NEVER !!!**

To instantiate an Activity : you MUST use an [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and let Android do the job.

Before coding anything else, please be sure to understand the [Android activity life-cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

To answer precisely to your question:

`messageHistoryText` is null when you use it in your custom constructor because your activity `Messaging` don't contains any view when you initialize it.
The method `findViewById` will always return null (whatever the id is) if you call it before setting the content of your Activity.

The most usual way to set the content of an Activity is to call [setContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)) in the [Activity.onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)) method (but do it **after** the call to `super.onCreate(bundle)` otherwise your Activity will not be *ready* to set it's content)

Comment: but i want to call the function.so i need to do that.

Comment: cant i access function from another activity .

Comment: Put your function somewhere else (I mean in a class that is NOT an Activity), or use Intent to communicate between activities, or ... there are many possibilities but certainly not creating an Activity with your own constructor !

Comment: my Qustion is still same how do i avoid getting messageHistoryText=null while tring to access from another activity.